# Filter to have keys with specific value only presto

Tags: sql, json, presto

I have a varchar column

```
{" l  l": 2, " m  m": 2, " xs  xs": 2, " xxs  xxs": 2, "s  s": 0, "xl  xl": 0}
```

How do I filter it to get only keys with values greater then 0?
Expected output is

```
{" l  l": 2, " m  m": 2, " xs  xs": 2, " xxs  xxs": 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like json so you can try to process it like one - parse as json, turn it into `map(varchar, integer)` (or `double`), filter, turn back into string:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(json_str) as (
    values ('{" l  l": 2, " m  m": 2, " xs  xs": 2, " xxs  xxs": 2, "s  s": 0, "xl  xl": 0}')
)

-- query
select json_format(cast( 
        map_filter(cast(json_parse(json_str) as  map(varchar, integer)), (k, v) -> v > 0) 
    as json))
from dataset;
```

Output:

```
                      _col0
-------------------------------------------------
 {" l  l":2," m  m":2," xs  xs":2," xxs  xxs":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to carry out this task is by:

- using `JSONB_EACH_TEXT` to convert your json to table
- filtering out values equal to 0
- recreating your json with `JSON_OBJECT` + `ARRAY_AGG`

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(ARRAY_AGG(k), ARRAY_AGG(v))
FROM tab
CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_EACH_TEXT(tab.string) AS j(k,v)
WHERE v::int > 0
```

Output:

| json_object |
| --- |
| {" l l":"2"," m m":"2"," xs xs":"2"," xxs xxs":"2"} |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iDyNALVz3PmWJcojPsmqir/0).